# Как кроссбраузерно сделать смену favicon через Java Script?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Требуется сделать динамическую смену favicon через JS, вроде той, что есть в VK (например, при прослушивании музыки). Желательно в теге с иконкой не использовать никаких дополнительных атрибутов (типа поиска по id). Есть решения, которые предполагают полное удаление этого тега, после чего добавление его заново, но они не кроссбраузерные (в частности, не работают в некоторых версиях Firefox и IE). Есть ли универсальное решение для этой задачи?